# after iOS 8 splitviewcontroller master view controller won't resize height on rotation

Tags: uiview, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an iOS project with a splitviewcontroller that is created in code. After building this on iOS8 the master (navigation side) of the splitviewcontroller is not resizing on rotation and maintains the height of whatever orientation the app was started in. In all previous versions it would take on the size of the view.

I've traced through - (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id)coordinator

and even tried to manually set my view's heights from there but it always keeps the starting height.

Any help with this is appreciated. I recognize that I don't have a lot of information included in this question but I am hopping there is a common issue that I'm not aware of with the iOS8 upgrade.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem in my project was that I was using a very outdated UIWindow that had some random incompatibility with iOS8. My solution was simply to just create my UIWindow in code [UIWindow alloc] rather than rely on the old .xib I was.

Comment: what did you do exactly?  Can you elaborate on the steps you took?  This problem is no joke..when I tried to create the UIWindow in code, when I rotate the first time, the whole splitView rotates offscreen until you rotate it back to original orientation, but my background image is gone and all views are empty except the titeView image in my rootViewController's navBar??

Comment: Literally the solution I did was:         self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: We may have different problems and maybe for you the problem is in the split view controller which is also something I create in code